# build context for docker image very large

Tags: docker

I have created a couple different directories on my host machine as I try to learn about Docker just to keep my dockerfiles organized.  My Dockerfile I just ran looks like this:

```
FROM crystal/centos
MAINTAINER crystal

ADD ./rpms/test.rpm ./rpms/ 
RUN yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall /rpms/test.rpm
```

My actual rpm is only 1 GB.  But when I try to do `sudo docker build -t="crystal/test" .`, I get sending build context to Docker daemon 3.5 GB.  Is there something else that I'm unaware of as you continue to build Docker images? Is my memory accumulating as I build more images in my other directories on my host machine?

Comment: The build context is all the files/directories in the current directory.

Comment: Keep only files you need for the build in this directory. That is, the Dockerfile and any local files/directories copied/added to the build image in the Dockerfile. Also, make use of `.dockerignore`

Answer (score 531, accepted):

The Docker client sends the entire "build context" to the Docker daemon. That build context (by default) is the entire directory the `Dockerfile` is in (so, the entire `rpms` tree).

You can setup a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file to get Docker to ignore some files. You might want to experiment with it.

Alternatively, you can move your `rpms` folder one directory level above your `Dockerfile`, and only symlink `test.rpm` into the `Dockerfile`'s directory.

---

You’ll often want to **add the `.git` folder to the `.dockerignore`** which was the cause of a 150MB -> 5GB difference for some users in the comments here.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that symlinking is not possible in this case since the `ADD` command does not follow sym links during a build.  See: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1676

Comment: lifesaver ! Rails developers: be sure to add `tmp` `log` to `.dockerignore` + other custom ones

Comment: don't forget to add .git folder to .dockerignore file (assuming you are using git)

Comment: Yep, `.git` folder is included by default - this definitely caught me out.

Comment: What is the "build context" exactly? I tried to look for these files using the docker build RUN command, but I don't see the files in my Dockerfile folder inside the docker filesystem (during build time.) Can someone please give me a simple example how build context is useful?

Comment: I was having that same situation. docker build was taking long time. As soon as i added .dockerignore and executed command build it reached to the npm install quickly.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is still very relevant.
You helped me reducing the size of context from 72MB to 4KB which subsequently also reduced the build time.

Comment: My issue was a bit weird but still I think I lost 30 min. I was rushing and I placed my Dockerfile in the home folder where I had a lot of other things, the context was taking all of them and I was not able to build. I just needed to switch the Dockerfile in an empty directory and I had no problems again

Comment: the symlink idea is not working, it complains about it.

Answer (score 106):

## Update 2019

Starting from Docker v18.06 there is an option to use a new image builder called [Build Kit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

It's pre-bundled with the Docker, no need to install anything. It's backward compatible with the `Dockerfile` syntax, no need to change the `Dockerfile`.

### Legacy Docker Build vs New Docker BuildKit

Here is an example of building an image with a huge unused file in the build directory:

**Legacy Docker Build:**

```sh
$ time docker image build --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.315GB
[...]
Successfully built c9ec5d33e12e

real    0m51.035s
user    0m7.189s
sys 0m10.712s
```

**New Docker BuildKit:**

```sh
$ time DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker image build --no-cache .
[+] Building 0.1s (5/5) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
[...]
 => => writing image sha256:ba5bca3a525ac97573b2e1d3cb936ad50cf8129eedfa9  0.0s

real    0m0.166s
user    0m0.034s
sys 0m0.026s
```

The only change is the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable, the difference in time is huge.

### `.dockerignore` File

Please note, that the `.dockerignore` file is still valid and useful. Some `Dockerfile` commands like `COPY . .` will still take into account the `.dockerignore` rules. But the side files in the build directory (not referenced in the `Dockerfile`) are not getting copied anymore as a "build context" by the BuildKit.

Comment: It is important to note that DOCKER_BUILDKIT is not currently supported for Windows Containers.  (Linux Only, Listed under limitations: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)

Comment: This seems disingenuous; buildkit is still sending the build context first.
How exactly did the build context go from 4.3GB to ??B and 0s just by turning on the option? Because that's not my experience; I had the same context size transferred:
```=> [internal] load build context
=> => transferring context: 924.39MB    86.3s``` you just `[...]` the lines that should show 4.3 GB at least the first time its run.

Granted the second time, it doesn't re-transfer the context, which is what we all needed.

Comment: @dlamblin pls see the `.dockerignore` section of the answer: BuildKit does not copy anymore the side files in the build directory (not referenced in the Dockerfile). Usually that's the case, but your experience might vary ;)

Comment: I see; you'd had unnecessary files in the build context, while I had almost 1GB of necessary files. Now... buildkit IS MUCH BETTER. It doesn't retransmit the files for cached rebuilds of a failure, and it apparently only moves the files needed (as you point out)

Comment: it is insane how well this works. ```time DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker image build --no-cache -t my-image-name-come-here .```

Answer (score 27):

I fixed it by moving my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml into a subfolder and it worked great.  Apparently docker sends the current folder to the daemon and my folder was 9 gigs.

Comment: This method gives Forbidden path: outside the build context error if a file from a parent directory is being copied , any solution for this?

Comment: excluding from .dockerignore might provide the same result; or does it offers more benefits ?

Answer (score 22):

If you have a `.dockerignore` file and build context is still large, you can check what is being sent to the docker build context using [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Advanced-Usage):

```
ag --path-to-ignore .dockerignore --files-with-matches
```

Note that some `**` patterns might not work properly.

See this Github issue for additional comments: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16056

Comment: You're my savior! I had 5GB of data I simply forgot about....

Answer (score 20):

An option to troubleshoot large context problems caused by inadequate `.dockerignore` exclusions is to use this command:

`rg -uuu --ignore-file .dockerignore --files --sort path .`

Which uses this tool: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

It works really well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've built on your answer, adding each file's size and sort in descending order:

`rg -uuu --ignore-file .dockerignore --files --sort path . | xargs ls -lh | awk '{print $5,$9}' | sort -hrk 1 | head -n 20`

Comment: Fantastic. That was just what I needed. Far more straightforward and effective than the `ncdu` approach I previously tried.

Answer (score 7):

In my case that was when i execute with wrong `-f` arguments - without path to directory where located Dockerfile

`docker build --no-cache -t nginx5 -f /home/DF/Dockerfile /home/DF/` - right

`docker build --no-cache -t nginx5 -f /home/DF/Dockerfile` - wrong

Answer (score 6):

For `NodeJS Application`, add a `.dockerignore` file your root project directory and inside the `.dockerignore` file add the following

```
node_modules
dist
```

Comment: I would even add `.git` and `*Dockerfile*`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be in full control of your build context you could also build the container completely without any context and `COPY` relevant data into the container afterwards.

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

One downside of this would be that with this approach you can only `ADD` things in the dockerfile referencing to a remote URL, and not files from your local host.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--

Answer (score 3):

Just to summarize what you can do if your Docker image build context too large:

- make sure you don't have unused files in the context (unused files - those that still untouchable during image building);
- add unused files and/or directories to .dockerignore (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604307/4838518));
- make sure you specify the right folder as an image build context (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33330203/4838518));
- try to use BuildKit with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280541/4838518));
- try to split your project into smaller parts to optimize content of build context;
- if you have a complex project you may want to manually collect all necessary files in separate folder before build and use it as a build context for a specific image.

Answer (score 2):

if you are creating image and getting message
**sending build context to docker daemon** which is taking log time to copy,

then add **.dockerignore file**. it should include the files or directory which
does not need to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

The great tool to inspect the built docker image is `dive`
https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Here're the instructions from the official readme:

To analyze a Docker image simply run dive with an image tag/id/digest:

```sh
dive <your-image-tag>
```

or if you want to build your image then jump straight into analyzing it:

```sh
dive build -t <some-tag> .
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as FreeStyler.  However I was building from a directory one up from my context. So the -f arguments were correct the context was incorrect.

```
project 
|
-------docker-dir
```

Building from the docker-dir the following was fine

```
docker build -t br_base:0.1 .
```

Building from the dock-dir the the build context changed. Therefore I needed to change the context in the command. Context is given by the '.' in the command above.

The the new command from the project directory should be

```
docker build -t br_base:0.1 ./base
```

Context here is given by the './base'