# I found an image on docker hub that I like but doesn't meet my needs. How do I update it and make it my own?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I found an image on docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/realbazso/horizon) that I like. I am trying to update this to where it runs the most current version of this software.

I tested running the image with the arguments provided and it works great, but the version of the VMWare Horizon client that the image has does not have an updated SSL library and cannot connect to the servers I need it to without throwing an SSL error.

I'm super new to docker, but I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. I'm wanting to install it on the ubuntu:14.04 image, but I'm just not able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Have you already gone through the [Getting started with Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/) tutorial? [Build your own image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) section has a few examples to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

as you have the recipe, if you look at 
https://hub.docker.com/r/realbazso/horizon/~/dockerfile/

you should create a directory, put this Dockerfile in, modify it, build another image

`docker build -t tucker/myhorizon .`

launch it, test it, modify again the Dockerfile maybe.

Check the doc R0MANARMY listed

Comment: It is wise to create a directory and put the Dockerfile and all the stuff needed by your image in it, in order to avoid some surprises if you have a lot of files in your home directory, and put the Dockerfile in it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600769/build-context-for-docker-image-very-large

Answer (score 1):

I am going to add some more information to @user2915097's answer.

The first thing to do when you want to edit/update an already existing image is to see if you can find its Dockerfile. Fortunately, this repo has a Dockerfile attached to it so it makes it easier. I commented the file so that you can understand better what is going on:

```
# Pulls the ubuntu image. This will serve as the base image for the container. You could change this and use ubuntu:16.04 to get the latest LTS.
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# RUN will execute the commands for you when you build the image from this Dockerfile. This is probably where you will want to change the source
RUN     echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y vmware-view-client

# CMD will execute the command (there can only be one!) when you start/run the container
CMD /usr/bin/vmware-view
```

A good resource to understand those commands is https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/. Make sure to visit that page to learn more about Dockerfile!

Once you have a Dockerfile ready to build, navigate to the folder where your Dockerfile is and run:

```
# Make sure to change the argument of -t    
docker build -t yourDockerHubUsername/containerName .
```

You might need to modify your Dockerfile a few times before it works correctly. If you are having issues with Docker using cached data