# Why docker build is so slow

Tags: performance, docker

My docker is very slow when I'm trying to build images on my laptop.
I tried to build same image at my ubuntu inside virtual machine with same docker version and it builds it in 5 seconds, but on my laptop it evaluates every statement like 30 times slower. 
Even `ENV` command!

Laptop uses OpenSUSE 42.2 Leap with Btrfs as root file system, HDD with 5400 rpm and also it's encrypted.
I know all these factors but are they so significant that my build takes 15mins instead of 5sec?

Docker 1.13.1.

Thanks.

**UPD.**

not sure if it helps or not, but when I run `docker build -t test .` on my virtual machine, it uses 10% of my 4-core CPU for 5 secs and heavilly uses HDD.

however on laptop it uses one core of my 4-core CPU for 100% all the time and HDD remains idle almost all the time.

here is nmon statistics:
[image]

Comment: do you have your Dockerfile and all your needed files in a specific directory? If not the "buid context" is all your files of your current directory, and that will be slow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600769/build-context-for-docker-image-very-large

Comment: yup, I have all my files inside build context and it's just a bunch of bash scripts

Comment: so `strace docker build` maybe a big hammer, but should show what happens during your 15 minutes

Comment: not sure if it helps or not, but when I run `docker build -t test .` on my virtual machine, it uses 10% of my 4-core CPU for 5 secs and heavilly uses HDD.

however on laptop it uses one core of my 4-core CPU for 100% all the time and HDD remains idle almost all the time.

here is nmon statistics:
https://i.imgur.com/EHAkQ78.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like your laptops btrfs filesystem is having issues - as in it's fragmented. Try looking into tuning btrfs. I would also look into [this section of the docker documentation related to docker and btrfs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver) - specifically the section on performance which points to fragmentation.

Comment: I assume you mean it might be currently *fragmented*, en _needs_ to be defragmented? Not that I know much about btrfs, so it's mostly from a linguistic point of view ;)

Comment: thanks, that's correct. I should have said fragmented - updated it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I tried to defragment my fs and it didn't help

Comment: I would try to upgrade docker and follow the instructions in the link above that mentions how you should configure docker with btrfs. This still sounds like a btrfs and docker issue.

Comment: you were right. it was btrfs problem. i just moved docker directory to XFS and now it works fine

Comment: @abdollar How can I defragment it on macOS?

Comment: @VictorJohn mac's don't typically use btrfs - the command for btrfs is balance, such as - sudo btrfs filesystem balance /var/lib/docker - the mac filesystem auto defrags but you can call it manually search for 'optimize disk' using spotlight

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if this was the same problem but just made my build go from 5 **minutes** to 5 **seconds**, by adding the following `.dockerignore` file to the same directory as my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
**/bin
**/obj
**/node_modules
.git
```

Comment: Just one addition: The `.dockerignore` file needs to be in the docker compose context root directory, which can be different from the `docker-compose.yml` file location.

Comment: In my case, `top` revealed that more than 100% of a CPU was used by scand. An appropriate .gitignore helped.