# docker-compose up --build becomes very slow using cloud docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-machine

docker-compose up --build becomes very slow using cloud docker-machine and after one hour i have and error of a not found entrypoint.sh file.

On local Mac docker-machine same config work fine.

**My docker file**

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD app/ /code/
ADD static/ /code/
ADD entrypoint.sh /code/
```

**my docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app.wsgi
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    expose:
      - "80"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
```

**commands I run**

```
cd myprojectfolder
eval $(docker-machine env [my-cloud-machine-name])
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f envs/prd/prd.yml up --build -d
```

**error i have after one hour (my project files are only 40mb)**
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrypoint.sh\": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Please help me
Thanks

I changed as suggested to this configuration but nothing changed. I'm stuck on this:

docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Sending auth config ()

**this is my new config**

**docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app.wsgi
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    expose:
      - "80"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
```

**my prd.yml file**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./envs/prd/Dockerfile

  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./envs/prd/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**my prd dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD app/ ./app
ADD static/ ./static
ADD envs/prd/settings.py /app/settings.py
ADD entrypoint.sh .
```

**my .dockerignore**

```
.DS_Store
.dockerignore
.git/
.gitignore
README.rst
README.md
*.pyc
__pycache__
.idea/*
```

Comment: Your volume is getting mounted within the docker machine host. `volumes:
- .:/code` You need to either use `docker-machine mount` to mount the local folder within docker-machine host or run the image without a volume.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain better how i need to change dockerfile an docker compose file in order to use without volumes? i'm a beginner sorry! thankyou

Comment: remove `volumes: - .:/code`

Comment: i'm sorry but nothing changed. Removed volumes from web container. When i run: docker-compose --verbose -f docker-compose.yml -f envs/prd/prd.yml up --build -d I'm stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build context for docker image very large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600769/build-context-for-docker-image-very-large)

Comment: Thank you, WORK!  I did not know that even if you specific what add in the docker file all project files are added if not ignored on .dockerignore file

Answer (score 1):

Remove the volume declarations from your docker-compose and instead copy all relevant files in during the build stage (in your Dockerfile). For example in your `web` service remove `volumes: .:/code` and add `COPY * /code` to its Dockerfile.